# How to make PyLance parse NumPy style docstring properly in VSCode?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

Consider the following function

```
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    """ Add two numbers

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : int
        First integer
    y : int
        Second integer

    Returns
    int
        Results

    """
    return x + y
```

When I hover my mouse over `add` I get the following (LHS using `Jedi` and RHS using `PyLance`)

[image]

Is there a known way to get `PyLance` parse the docstring properly like `Jedi` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I reproduced this problem.

Thank you for posting this problem here, and we have already submitted it, let us look forward to the improvement of this function.

Github link: [How to keep the content of Parameter suggestions displayed by Pylance in the original style?](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/744)

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. IIRC, you'll need to attach a link to this question in your GitHub issue to avoid SO's copyright issues (I saw it discussed somewhere in meta).